Issues with GitHub Repository Not Being Computed in SonarCloud
I am a beginner with SonarCloud and I am facing an issue where my GitHub repository is not being computed in SonarCloud. Despite following the setup instructions, my code analysis is not being performed, and I see a "not computed" message as shown in the image below:
enter image description here
What I've Tried:
I ensured that my repository is correctly linked to SonarCloud.
Verified that the necessary permissions are granted for SonarCloud to access my GitHub repository.
Triggered a manual analysis from the SonarCloud dashboard.
Checked for any error messages or logs in SonarCloud, but didn't find anything obvious.
Despite these efforts, the issue persists. I am not sure what I might be missing. Could anyone guide me on how to resolve this issue?
